# Middleware error handling

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have a chain of [claw](https://github.com/go-zoo/claw) `http.Handler` middlewares, where my first handler might write an error response:

```
http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusUnauthorized)
```

However my other middlewares continue executing, but I don't want it to. What is the best way to go about this? I tried checking the status header after calling `http.Error()`, to see if it is other than a 200:

```
status := w.Header().Get("Status")
```

but status is an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a "naked" `return` just after your error to stop the middleware chain execution.

From [http documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Error):

> Error replies to the request with the specified error message and HTTP code. It does not otherwise end the request; the caller should ensure no further writes are done to w. The error message should be plain text.

From this [Custom Handlers and Avoiding Globals in Go Web Applications](http://elithrar.github.io/article/custom-handlers-avoiding-globals/) :

```
func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, err := store.Get(r, "myapp")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusInternalServerError), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return // Forget to return, and the handler will continue on
    }
    .../...
}
```